# MvvmCross 6.4.1 Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>() have failed, do not find the constructor

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

After update MvvmCross to 6.4.1, to start a project Xamarin.IOS the Mvx.Resolve is deprecated, then now I use `Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve()`, but an error happens below:

`Failed to resolve type MvvmCross.ViewModels.IMvxAppStart Stacktrace:  at MvvmCross.IoC.MvxIoCContainer.Resolve (System.Type t) [0x0001c] in D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross\IoC\MvxIoCContainer.cs:252 at MvvmCross.IoC.MvxIoCContainer.Resolve[T] () [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross\IoC\MvxIoCContainer.cs:242 at MvvmCross.IoC.MvxIoCProvider.Resolve[T] () [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross\IoC\MvxIoCProvider.cs:66 at Fidelity.FCS.iOS.AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching (UIKit.UIApplication application, Foundation.NSDictionary launchOptions) [0x0015d] in ProjectName/AppDelegate.cs:98 at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr) at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.6.0.12/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:86 at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0000e] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.6.0.12/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:65 at Fidelity.FCS.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in ProjectName/Main.cs:13`

below the section of code in AppDelegate, that happen the error:

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, true);

Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

var presenter = new CustomMvxIosViewPresenter(this, Window);

var setup = new Setup(this, presenter); 
setup.PlatformInitialize();

//here , in this call, happens the error 
var startup = Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<ImvxAppStart>();
startup.Start();

Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
```

I am using Visual Studio for Mac My configuration of Visual Studio For Mac:

```
Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac Version 8.3.11 (build 1) Installation UUID: 0672de6a-2768-4316-8e45-910515627427 GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme) Xamarin.Mac 5.16.1.24 (d16-3 / 08809f5b)

Package version: 604000208

Mono Framework MDK Runtime: Mono 6.4.0.208 (2019-06/07c23f2ca43) (64-bit) Package version: 604000208

Xamarin Designer Version: 16.3.0.256 Hash: 8a223bfd7 Branch: remotes/origin/d16-3 Build date: 2019-11-01 21:02:02 UTC

NuGet Version: 5.3.0.6192

.NET Core SDK SDK: Not installed MSBuild SDKs: /Users/iterative/5.18.1/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Sdks

.NET Core Runtime Runtime: Not installed

Xamarin.Profiler Version: 1.6.12.29 Location: /Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler

Updater Version: 11

Apple Developer Tools Xcode 11.2.1 (15526.1) Build 11B53

Xamarin.Mac Version: 6.6.0.12 (Visual Studio Community) Hash: e3c2b406d Branch: xcode11.2 Build date: 2019-11-01 00:12:07-0400

Xamarin.iOS Version: 13.6.0.12 (Visual Studio Community) Hash: e3c2b406d Branch: xcode11.2 Build date: 2019-11-01 00:12:08-0400

Xamarin.Android Version: 10.0.6.2 (Visual Studio Community) Commit: xamarin-android/d16-3/c407838 Android SDK: /Users/iterative/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx Supported Android versions: 7.1 (API level 25) 8.0 (API level 26) 8.1 (API level 27)

SDK Tools Version: 26.1.1 SDK Platform Tools Version: 29.0.5 SDK Build Tools Version: 29.0.2

Build Information: Mono: mono/mono/2019-06@476d72b9e32 Java.Interop: xamarin/java.interop/d16-3@5836f58 LibZipSharp: grendello/LibZipSharp/d16-3@71f4a94 LibZip: nih-at/libzip/rel-1-5-1@b95cf3fd ProGuard: xamarin/proguard/master@905836d SQLite: xamarin/sqlite/3.27.1@8212a2d Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/d16-3@cb41333
Microsoft Mobile OpenJDK Java SDK: /Users/iterative/Library/Developer/Xamarin/jdk/microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25 1.8.0-25 Android Designer EPL code available here: https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL
Android SDK Manager Version: 1.4.0.65 Hash: c33b107 Branch: remotes/origin/d16-3 Build date: 2019-11-19 20:33:22 UTC
Android Device Manager Version: 1.2.0.116 Hash: d2b2af0 Branch: remotes/origin/d16-3 Build date: 2019-11-19 20:33:42 UTC
Xamarin Inspector Version: 1.4.3 Hash: db27525 Branch: 1.4-release Build date: Mon, 09 Jul 2018 21:20:18 GMT Client compatibility: 1

Build Information Release ID: 803110001 Git revision: 6ee6ad2ec46ae5a08a1999ee4c815ac656a35b91 Build date: 2019-12-05 16:09:27+00 Build branch: release-8.3 
Xamarin extensions: 56bd70ef2e327f71c615cfc29a47fd50685fadcb

Operating System Mac OS X 10.14.6 Darwin 18.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0 Tue Aug 20 16:57:14 PDT 2019 root:xnu-4903.271.2~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Comment: Can you share the code of ImvxAppStart.cs and MvxIoCContainer.cs?

Comment: Do you have class inherited by MvxAppStart class?

Answer (score 1):

I just had to figure this out and as there is no answer - I fixed this issue by adding the following line -

MvxIosSetupSingleton.EnsureSingletonAvailable(this,presenter).EnsureInitialized();

So my app delegate uses

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
            _window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
            var presenter = IsPad? (IMvxIosViewPresenter)new 
            SplitViewPresenter(this,_window) : new SingleViewPresenter(this, _window);

            var setup = new Setup();
            setup.PlatformInitialize(this , presenter);

                MvxIosSetupSingleton.EnsureSingletonAvailable(this,presenter).EnsureInitialized();

            var startup = Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>();
            startup.Start();
            _window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

            return true;
        }
```